# Node.JS HTTPS request with Digest authentication

Tags: node.js, https, digest-authentication

I'm trying to make a **HTTPS request** to a service that requires **Digest authentication** from **Node.JS** v8.11.2 script but can't figure out the authentication part.

I tried this but don't know how to implement the digest authentication (FYI it's a test server just for the authentication - username `test` and password `Passw0rd` just in case someone would like to test the script).

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  hostname: 'digest.dev.e-it.nz',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);
});
```

Any idea how to do that? Note that it's not *Basic authentication*, that's different and easy.
Thanks!